# Is using "this->variable" slower than using just "variable"

Tags: c++, class, pointers, variables

so if i have a class

```
class newclass
{
  int length;
  int breadth;
  public:
  int area()
    {
        return this->length * this->breadth;
      }
  int area2()
    {
        return length * bredth;
       }

};
```

which of the two methods will be faster area 1 or area 2, which should be used?

Comment: They're identical.

Comment: Did you check the assembly? https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qYr1GExjh

Comment: The two are functionally equivalent, so no difference at run time.   Any difference in compilation time will be compiler-specific, but probably negligible.    Note that there are some contexts where `this->` is necessary, but your example is not one of those.    Generally speaking, I would not use `this->` unless its usage is necessary - but that's purely a stylistic concern (avoiding unnecessary typing).

Comment: @StephenNewell i should have checked this in the first place.

Comment: @StephenNewell that doesn't mean much.  A good optimizing compiler can remove a lot of extraneous fluff even when the source code isn't identical.

Comment: Slower to type in, I suppose... the code that is generated will be the same.

Comment: Yes, it's slower, because there are more characters to type and, more important, more to read before figuring out that it's just noise. Save it for the places where it's needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler will treat those as identical. Use `this->variable` instead of `variable` if it helps the reader better read the code.

Comment: Thanks, i like using this->variable because sometimes i use the same names for the parameters in the function for ex int setLength(int length){ this->length = length;} is guess you can say this is sort of variable overloading as i am kind of using the same variable name twice.

Comment: I'm having trouble thinking of an example where adding an extraneous `this->` would make the code more readable.

Comment: @Free-Man I use the Microsoft convention of starting all member variables with `m_` so I never have that situation.

Comment: @MarkRansom I'm having trouble thinking of an example where adding an extraneous `m_` would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

> Is using “this->variable” slower than using just “variable”

Its slower to type.

It's not slower at runtime.